# how to write expression in sed to control matching multiple occurences in the same line

Tags: sed

lets say I have

```
apples bananas oranges pomelos oranges
```

bananas and pomelos are strings that vary.

I use `sed 's/apples.*oranges/applesandfriends/'` , it matches the second `oranges` of the line.

How do I control which occurrence of `oranges` to match?

The result I get,

```
applesandfriends
```

The result I want,

```
applesandfriends pomelos oranges
```

Comment: Could you specify what is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: Why can't you just use: `sed 's|apples bananas oranges|applesandfriends|'`?

Comment: @guillermochamorro Sometimes I want to match patterns that occur multiple times in a line. However, .* expansion expands to the very last one always.

Comment: @NasirRiley Because bananas is a substitute for a string that would be represented by .* . But the expansion expands over to pomelos as well, which not I'm looking for.

Comment: basic regex and extended regex do not have "non-greedy" matching. You can use perl: `perl -pe 's/apples.*?oranges/applesandfriends/'` -- note the `*?` quantifier.

Comment: This is the result you want: `applesandfriends pomelos oranges`?

Comment: @guillermochamorro yes I added it to my post too.

Comment: What I've came up using sed, is a subtitution of the first oranges for any special char, and then make the subtitution  to that char. Meaning: `echo $foo | sed 's/oranges/#/1' | sed 's/apples.*#/applesandfriends/'`

Comment: @guillermochamorro.  `sed` does not support non-greedy matching. Your two-step technique is the "standard" workaround for this limitation.

Comment: @glennjackman it works, but the two-step by guillermo is more fine-grained. Thank you.

Comment: @fmurphy Thank you, I read your comment and learn from it, but I wanted to come wit a "pure" sed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`, subtituting the nth keyword (orange) for a special char, and then perform the match until that char:

```
foo="apples bananas oranges pomelos oranges "

echo $foo | sed 's/oranges/#/1' | sed 's/apples.*#/applesandfriends/'
```

Output:

```
applesandfriends pomelos oranges
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below method by removing first occurences of orange in file

```
perl -pne "s/ /\n/g" o.txt|sed '/^$/d'| sed '0,/oranges/s/oranges//g'| sed '/^$/d'| perl -pne "s/\n/ /g"| sed "s/apples.*bananas/applesandfriends/g"
```

output

```
applesandfriends pomelos oranges
```